# Are ggplot point shapes svg files? Where can I find it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg

I made some cluster analysis with a cities database, and now I want to use the same symbols for each cluster in a fancy map using QGis. Thanks!

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: according to the discussion on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72518549/16730940 the shapes (which are R default shapes, not ggplot specific) are effectively stored as a custom font?  It does include some suggestions for making custom ones, if you want to use the same custom one for both maps.