# How to assign different images to different vertices in an igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975681/r-creating-graphs-where-the-nodes-are-images) which seems similar but I am having difficulty getting it to work with my data.

Let's say my edgelist consists of the following:

```
P1 P2 weight
a  b  1
a  c  3
a  d  2
b  c  8
```

I use `read.csv` to collect the data, and then I convert it to a matrix.  Then I graph it using the following:

```
g=graph.edgelist(x[,1:2],directed=F)
E(g)$weight=as.numeric(x[,3])
tkplot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,edge.width=E(g)$weight)
```

And this returns a network with vertices and edges.  I would like to replace vertex a with one image, vertex b with another and so on.  I know how to apply the same image to all, but I want to apply a different image to every vertex.  How do I go about doing this?

**Edit**: Adding reproducible code below as requested by [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189497/how-to-assign-different-images-to-different-vertices-in-an-igraph/29189960?noredirect=1#comment46613276_29189960)

```
# loading libraries
library(igraph)
library(rgdal)

# reading data from edgelist
x <- read.csv('edgelist', colClasses = c("character","character","numeric"), header=T)
# however, to replicate the data, use this line instead (Above line included just to show how I get the data)
x <- data.frame(P1 = c("a","a","a","b"), P2 = c("b","c","d","c"), weight = c(1,3,2,8))

# converting x to a matrix
x = as.matrix(x)

# preparing graph (getting rid of arrows, edge colors)
g = graph.edgelist(x[,1:2], directed=F)
E(g)$weight=as.numeric(x[,3])
E(g)[weight<=1]$color='dodgerblue'
E(g)[weight>=2&weight<=3]$color='dodgerblue1'
E(g)[weight>=4&weight<=7]$color='dodgerblue2'
E(g)[weight>=8&weight<=9]$color='dodgerblue3'
E(g)[weight==10]$color='dodgerblue4'

# plot the graph 
# beginning of stuff I do not do anymore - the tkplot and adj lines below here I do not do anymore as they have been replaced with suggestions by user20650
tkplot(g, canvas.width=640, canvas.height=640, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, edge.width=E(g)$weight)

# just to make sure everything is correct, I was also verifying with this
adj <- get.adjacency(g, attr='weight')
# end of stuff I do not do anymore and I replaced it with what follows

# this is where I started placing user20650's lines (survcont1.png through survcont13.png are local files - 1 is the image for a, 2 for b, and so on)
url <- paste0("survcont", 1:13, ".png")

# my mapply which I guess I don't need anymore (I'm using rgdal because it is a library I already have that can read the images, am willing to use a better method if one exists)
mapply(readGDAL, url)
img <- lapply(url, png::readPNG)

set.seed(1)
adj <- matrix(sample(0:1,3^2,T,prob=c(0.8,0.8)),13,13)
g <- graph.adjacency(adj)
set.seed(1)

l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
l[,1]=(l[,1]-min(l[,1]))/(max(l[,1])-min(l[,1]))*2-1
l[,2]=(l[,2]-min(l[,2]))/(max(l[,2])-min(l[,2]))*2-1

# I added in the label so I can verify if the right vertices are showing up in the right places, I will remove in final version, also added in the edge weights
plot(g, layout=l, vertex.size=10, vertex.shape="square", vertex.color="#00000000", vertex.frame.color="#00000000", vertex.label="", edge.width=E(g)$weight)

# and finally plotting of the images
for(i in 1:nrow(l)) {  
  rasterImage(img[[i]], l[i, 1]-0.2, l[i, 2]-0.2, l[i, 1]+0.2, l[i, 2]+0.2)
}
```

I am guessing something is going wrong with the adj line and I'm somehow not linking my data to the images.  I also don't get why I need to set.seed.

The images plot, which is great, but my original edge widths and colors do not and I am not sure image 1 is linking to a, 2 to b, and so on.

Comment: See http://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph.vertex.shapes.html ; the last example has it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Sacha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975681/r-creating-graphs-where-the-nodes-are-images/4978111#4978111) in the question you link to, to do this. If your images are stored in a list, just iterate through it to render the png files. I had to tweak the manual adjustment (from 0.1 to 0.2) to resize the image.

**EDIT** Using OP's data and adding edge weight and colour (deleted original post as this largely repeats it)

First need some images for the vertices.

```
# As i dont have access to your images i will download and use the 
# images as before. We need four images as there are four vertices
# You dont need to do this bit exactly, all you need to do is read 
# in your images into your R session, in a list called img

url <- paste0("http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG", 1632:1635, ".png")
mapply(download.file, url, basename(url))
img <- lapply( basename(url), png::readPNG)
```

```
library(igraph)

# data
x <- data.frame(P1 = c("a","a","a","b"), 
                P2 = c("b","c","d","c"), 
                weight = c(1,3,2,8))

# this reads in the third column which you can then assign to be weights
g <- graph.data.frame(x, directed=FALSE)
# check
E(g)$weight

# edge colour - you might need to tweak this depending on your
# data, with the right argument etc
E(g)$colour <- as.character(cut(as.numeric(E(g)$weight), 
                      breaks = c(0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10), 
                      labels=paste0("dodgerblue", c("", 1:4))))

# you need to set the seed as the layout function is an 
# iterative process and not deterministic
set.seed(1)    
l <- layout.norm(layout.fruchterman.reingold(g), 
                           xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1)


par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(g, layout=l, vertex.size=20, vertex.shape="square", 
     vertex.color="#00000000", vertex.frame.color="#00000000", 
     vertex.label="", edge.width=E(g)$weight, edge.color=E(g)$colour)

# and finally plotting of the images
for(i in 1:nrow(l)) {  
  rasterImage(img[[i]], l[i, 1]-0.2, l[i, 2]-0.2, l[i, 1]+0.2, l[i, 2]+0.2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this but I'm using local images so I replaced your first section with `url <- paste0("survcont", 1:13, ".png"); mapply(readGDAL, url); img <- lapply(url, png::readPNG)`.  But when I run the plot (even when I append `edge.width=E(g)$weight`) I get the same lines you do in your example and the lines' thickness in my original example where based on the weight.   And once I remove the `vertex.label=""` I get the numbers from the images rather than the letters from my matrix.  I know I'm probably missing something really obvious but I can't figure out what's wrong.  BTW, the images load.

Comment: ok,I don;t quite follow , sorry.  If the images are local you would not need the`mapply` stage of my code - I just downloaded the images to have a reproducible example. Why are you using  `readGDAL`? Please can you edit your question with an minimal example   (perhaps using a similar approach to my answer) showing all codes and where the problem is. Ty

Comment: I added the example.  I use readGDAL because I use that library for reading images for other projects and I'm just used to it.  I can change that if there is a better way (which there always is in R).

Comment: ok, thanks, ill update. You seem to be overwriting your graph `g`, with the one i generate. Ill update using your data (but ill have to use dummy images)