# Matplotlib: How to plot images instead of points?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

I want to read a list of images into Python/Matplotlib and then plot this images instead of other markers (like points) in a graph. I have tried with imshow but I didn't succeed, because I cannot shift the image to another position and scale it appropriately. Maybe somebody has a good idea : )
[image: It should look somehow like this! (Without the Spongebob, but with very serious data of course!)]

Comment: There are some other questions about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860417/placing-custom-images-in-a-plot-window-as-custom-data-markers-or-to-annotate-t) and [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/custom-markers-from-images-td4166.html), although whether those solutions will work for you depends on exactly what you need.

Comment: Try this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Plot the image using `imshow` with the `extent` kwarg set based on the location you want the image at.
2. Use an `OffsetImage` inside an `AnnotationBbox`.

The first way is the easiest to understand, but the second has a large advantage. The annotation box approach will allow the image to stay at a constant size as you zoom in.  Using `imshow` will tie the size of the image to the data coordinates of the plot.

Here's an example of the second option:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
    y = np.cos(x)
    image_path = get_sample_data('ada.png')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    imscatter(x, y, image_path, zoom=0.1, ax=ax)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

def imscatter(x, y, image, ax=None, zoom=1):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    try:
        image = plt.imread(image)
    except TypeError:
        # Likely already an array...
        pass
    im = OffsetImage(image, zoom=zoom)
    x, y = np.atleast_1d(x, y)
    artists = []
    for x0, y0 in zip(x, y):
        ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x0, y0), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
        artists.append(ax.add_artist(ab))
    ax.update_datalim(np.column_stack([x, y]))
    ax.autoscale()
    return artists

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Is that Ada Lovelace? Awesome.

Comment: I've tried your method, and it does not work for me. Do you think you could take a look at my follow-up question? It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896088/

Comment: this is great, also just pointing out that the zoom parameter can be used to control the size of the points (specified as images)

Answer (score 55):

**If you want different images:**

This is now the first reply when googling "matplotlib scatter with images". If you're like me and actually need to plot different images on each image, try this minimalied example instead. Just be sure to input  your own images.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

def getImage(path, zoom=1):
    return OffsetImage(plt.imread(path), zoom=zoom)

paths = [
    'a.jpg',
    'b.jpg',
    'c.jpg',
    'd.jpg',
    'e.jpg']
    
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y) 

for x0, y0, path in zip(x, y,paths):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage(path), (x0, y0), frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
```

[image]

Comment: I had to `ax.add_artist(ab)` at the end in the loop.  Is it possible it's left out of the example?

Comment: @JoshuaR. Yes, you're right. I was a little overzealous tidying up the example. `ax.add_artist(ab)` should indeed be added.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen what if I want to use only a single image for all points? Thanks

Comment: @pukumarathe In the current version, we pass a different value for `path` for each point. If you want the same image, you can pass the same value for `path` each time.  Or, even better load the image once `im = OffsetImage(plt.imread(path))` and then replace `getImage(path)` in the for loop to `im`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Great it works, the exactly I wanted. Thanks !! How can I reduce the size of marker image. Any suggestion?

Comment: `OffsetImage` takes an `zoom` parameter. You can play around with that, which can make the images smaller (or even larger, I think)