# Create a XY scatter plot consist of images

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create an XY scatter plot consisting of images. There area 100+ images. The images are have coordinates information in their file name ( for example ImageX1Y1.jpg , ImageX2Y-1.jpg). All images have the same resolution and pixel size

Below is an example of the manually done(manually insert in excel), partially completed, image XY scatter  plot

[image]

I have look around but found no answers for it to be done automatically, 
The closest to plotting images are here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566284/matplotlib-how-to-plot-images-instead-of-points)
I am thinking of pandas but it stores strings and not images
i welcome all solutions even though i am using python