# Is it possible to replace the bar of the chart with png images and make them expand based on the value given?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to build a single stacked clustered column chart to simulate earth's substances with their respective image legend. (e.g. https://ibb.co/cqUvv9)
For example, I want from 0 meters to -10 to show sand, right beneath from -10 to -25 rock, etc. and expand their respective png images based on their values.

So far I managed to build the clustered column with matplotlib, I just want to know if there's a way of showing images instead of bars.

Comment: [This example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html) may be of help. [Or this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/demo_ribbon_box.html). You may equally opt for a solution similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528024/insert-image-into-pie-chart-slice/44529673#44529673).