# How to create a Python Pie chart in the form of a coin?

Tags: python, pie-chart

So I would like to a create a pie chart in python that would show the pie chart in the form of a loonie( a $1 coin in Canada) and not as generic pie chart. Does anyone know how one would go a about doing it. I've been able to do it in excel and but it's a work around and I'd like to do it Python and automate the process for a number of different years. This video here shows what I'm trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htizndC8OIg&ab_channel=MrExcel.com. Any advice or help would be greatly appericiated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528024/insert-image-into-pie-chart-slice) help?

Comment: Yea it does, i'm gonna look into it. Thanks man!