# how to plot images instead of dots in a 3d matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, 3d, plot-annotations

I have a list like this, image for the path of each image file, xyz for the coordination of each image in the 3d figure:
[my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdiRx.png)

I searched below is a solution for 2D, which works fine, but obviously not working for 3d:
[Matplotlib: How to plot images instead of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566284/matplotlib-how-to-plot-images-instead-of-points)

I also searched for below- a solution for 3d, which works fine, but it only shows annotation text, rather than images:
[Matplotlib: Annotating a 3D scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)

can someone help? thanks.