# Texting Scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to text the name of each player in the graph. I have created the function below to print a pointplot.

```
def eficiencia_chart(datos):
    graph=sns.scatterplot('Eficiencia Defensiva','Eficiencia Ofensiva', data=datos, hue='Position')
    plt.xlim(roundup(max(datos['Eficiencia Defensiva'])),rounddown(min(datos['Eficiencia Defensiva'])))
    plt.ylim(rounddown(min(datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'])),roundup(max(datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'])))
    for line in range(0,datos.shape[0]):
        graph.text(datos['Eficiencia Defensiva'][line]+0.2, datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'][line], datos['Nombre'][line], size='medium')
        print(line)
    return graph
```

But when I execute it, only one name is printing and returns the message: `KeyError: 1`

[image]

By the way I would like to show a pic with the face of the player if possible instead of points. May somebody shed light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```py
graph.text(datos['Eficiencia Defensiva'].values[line]+0.2, datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'].values[line], datos['Nombre'].values[line], size='medium')
```

instead of

```py
graph.text(datos['Eficiencia Defensiva'][line]+0.2, datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'][line], datos['Nombre'][line], size='medium')
```

Because `df['key']` gives you a series, which can’t necessarily be accessed by integer indices, but `df['key'].values` on the other hand gives you a numpy array of the values which of course can be accessed with integer indices.

If that doesn’t work it likely means the shape of `datos` is not what you expect it to be and you should verify that `datos['Eficiencia Ofensiva'].values.shape[0] ==`datos.shape[0]`.

Comment: Hi William, Thank you very much for your quick response. Do you know how to print images for each point instead of points?

Comment: Are you asking how to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53851017/10659910)?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to represent each point with a face (because at the end are basketball players). In these case, all cases are represented with the same picture.

Comment: @MiguelSantos Actually, the answer I linked to (the bottom answer) uses different images - and the author specifically addresses that the other answer is only for using the same image while theirs is for using different images

Comment: Thank you. I will try proceding in this way