# Drawing circle hand drawn style by matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, shapes

I'm new to matprotlib. After plotting a graph I would like to mark a point. I do this with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(3, 2, s=500, edgecolor='#ff575a', lw=2, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, zorder=1) #6.5-row['mag']
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3])
```

The output:

[image]

Instead of the symmetric red circle is it possible to make a custom shape handwriting style? Something like this one:

[image]

I have tried to use the `AnnotationBbox` insted of ax.scatter:

```
ab = AnnotationBbox(OffsetImage(plt.imread('circle.png'), 
    zoom=0.2), (3, 2), frameon=False)
```

But that make the picture bad with some pixels of the circle missing, so it is not that sharp as the original png:

[image]

Comment: Store it as a png with transparency and plot it over your curve?

Comment: @Mr.T That could work, yes. Do you think programming way is too complicated? Or it is not possible with matplotlib?

Comment: Or perhaps save the graph plot in pdf/png and then with another software (e.g.: inkscape) you could add it manually and adjust it in and easier way

Comment: See for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22566284/8881141

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for the idea. I have checked that and tried with my code. But the .png image gets not that sharp when inserted. I have updated my question with that.

Comment: @JohanC can XKCD style be applied to the circle only?

Comment: You could use the `with` construction:  `with plt.xkcd(scale=10): ax.add_patch(Arc((3, 2), 0.3, 0.3, 0, 271, 270, edgecolor='#ff575a', lw=2, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, zorder=1))`

Comment: @JohanC I this your answer is the most close one, I would accept it if you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example code uses the xkcd style to draw a wiggly arc. You might need to experiment with the parameters for the best fit with your plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(3, 2, s=500, edgecolor='#ff575a', lw=2, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, zorder=1)  #
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3])
with plt.xkcd(scale=10):
    ax.add_patch(Arc((3, 2), 0.3, 0.3, angle=275, theta1=0, theta2=350,
                     edgecolor='#ff575a', lw=2, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, zorder=1))
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing a wiggly arc, xkcd style]